# Lightbox close link doesn't work in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, lightbox

While the [lightbox example page](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) works fine for me in IE7, I seem to have broken it in my implementation.

I've written a Lightbox plugin for [Mango Blog](http://mangoblog.org/) and everything works fine in Firefox. However, in IE7 the "close" button doesn't work. If I'm fast enough to get my cursor into the position that the close button will be placed before it slides into place, the IE status bar shows the "#" link, but clicking or moving the cursor makes the status bar go blank -- and of course nothing happens.

Not that it was that necessary, but I made a quick [screencast of the behavior in IE7](http://screencast.com/t/BxNpNoA9z). Note the cursor not switching to a hand on the close button.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try to use the actual 2.0.4 version of Lightbox as a base, there seem to be several changes in the DOM code, although nothing like the bug you described is mentioned in the changelog.

Comment: I didn't even realize I was behind on the version of Lightbox I was using, thanks!